# Copy links from image-dired to org-mode

Tags: emacs, org-mode, dired

I'm working with directories full of images, which are photographs of documents in an archive. I'm writing org files with notes on the content of these, and I would like to make it quicker and easier to browse the images (e.g. with *image-dired*) and copy links into the org-mode file alongside my notes.

My working setup looks like this:

[image: Image browser and org in emacs]

My questions are:

- How can I automatically copy a link for the currently displayed image into org?
- Is there any easy way to control the image-dired picture (browsing backwards and forwards, rotating) from within the org windows?
- Are there any other modes or tools that I should be looking at?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a little code to make working with images easier.  Just copy it into your `*scratch*` buffer and run `M-x eval-buffer`.

```
(defun my-next-image ()
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion 
    (with-current-buffer "*image-dired*"
      (image-dired-forward-image)
      (image-dired-display-thumbnail-original-image))))

(defun my-prev-image ()
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion 
    (with-current-buffer "*image-dired*"
      (image-dired-backward-image)
      (image-dired-display-thumbnail-original-image))))

(defun my-insert-current-image-path ()
  (interactive)
  (insert
   (concat
    "[["
    (save-excursion
      (with-current-buffer "*image-dired*"
        (image-dired-original-file-name)))
    "]]")))


(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "<f9> n") 'my-next-image)
(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "<f9> p") 'my-prev-image)
(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "<f9> i") 'my-insert-current-image-path)
```

Press `F9 n` to switch to the next image while in org mode, press `F9 i` to insert a link to the current image.  Rebind keys to your liking.

Comment: I know you're not supposed to say "thanks" on SE, but this was a great answer, and works very well. The pattern `(save-excursion (with-current-buffer …))` is one that I can use in lots of other places.

Comment: @meatwave Glad I could help, and best of luck for your PhD.